# Knowing if spans overlap

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, span

[image]

Only the first checked squares are deemed to be correct.
Why is D not correct? After all, the vectors do overlap on the same plane...

Comment: well does $z \in$ span $(x,w)$? No. $\hspace{1cm}$ So span$(x,w) \subset$ span$(x,y,z)$ and the reverse inclusion not true.

Comment: Yes... 1/5(25x+25y)+x=z........... z is in the span of x,w.

Comment: Am I the one who is lost ? :p

Comment: I guess you mean $1/5(25x+25y)+x=z$. I guess it should be right then.

Comment: Hmm.. Bhaskar, what do you think about the ABC then?

Comment: I guess I'll have to report there is a mistake in the assignment then.

Comment: Only C looks false

Comment: Perfect, do you know any other way of solving this problem rather then using the inclusion theorem?

Comment: C looks true also, as $x=(5z-w)/5$ and $w=5z-5x$

Comment: I guess I am making some mistake

Comment: Wow, that is also true... What is your level of education? Maybe we are just both not good at this.

Comment: do you have answer to this question. You sure only first two are correct?

Comment: When I inputed the answer as A and B by random guess, the computer told me I was right. I tried combination C and D, and B and C. The computer told me I was wrong.

Comment: well if you are considering vectors over Ring $\mathbb{Z}$, then division is not allowed. may be that is the case. Anything elese about the question. Is the field of scalars mentioned?

Comment: What do you mean Ring Z?

Comment: I mean the scalars, $2,3.4$ etc. are you taking them form integers or real numbers?

Comment: In my class, we limit ourselves to $R$.

Comment: well then I am sure, all are correct

Comment: check with your instructor though, tell me also if i am doing some silly overlooking here

Comment: Ok. Perfect. I'll warn her and you. I posted another interesting question if you have the time!

Comment: By the way Bhaskar, do you know if there is another way of solving the problem rather than using inclusion theorem?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990996/spans-and-dot-product-findin-the-linear-combination

Comment: I guess it is the best way to see if spanning set is contained in other or not. Somethimes , bases, dimension mismatching helps to prove that two spans are not same, but nothing like that here even if i assume $x$ and $y4 are lin. independent.

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth We were right! :)

Comment: yesss... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's explicitly show that all are true as long as the vector space is over a field. Note that $w$ and $z$ are both in Span($x,y$).

1. As $w = 25x + 25y$, we see that $w - 25x = 25y$, and so $y$ is in Span($w,x$). So for A, both sides are equal to Span($x,y$).
2. As $z$ is in Span($x,y$), both sides of B are equal to Span($x,y$).
3. As $z - 6x = 5y$, we see that $y$ is in Span($x,z$). So in fact Span($x,z$) = Span($x,y$). And as $5z - w = 5x$, we have firstly that $x$ is in Span($w,z$). But once we have $x$, we also get $y$, just as in 1. So Span($x,y$) = Span($w,z$).
4. We already know that Span($x,y,z$) = Span($x,y$). As $w - 25x = 25y$, we see that $y$ is in Span($x,w$). So again, both sides are Span($x,y$).

What you have are eight ways of writing Span($x,y$).